# Why entity getter returns null instead of 0?

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a field in database which is tinyint.

Here is part of entity responsible of this getter:

```
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="showAmounts", type="boolean", nullable=false)
 */
private $showamounts = 1;

/**
 * Get showamounts
 *
 * @return integer
 */
public function getShowamounts()
{
    return $this->showamounts;
}
```

And if showamounts = 0 then

```
echo $o->getShowamounts(); // returns "" instead of "0"
```

When I cast getter to int it's working, but I'm 100% sure that when I wrote the code (few months ago) everything worked ok. So my question is, what's happened? Maybe it's because of that, var in entity it's defined as boolean? I just want to store 0 or 1.

Comment: And is the type of the database column?

Comment: You should consider changing ```private $showamounts = 1;``` to ```private $showamounts = true;```. Doctrine converts true, false to 1, 0 for mysql but in your application you should always use true and false for the type ```boolean```.

Answer (score 4):

Try to var_dump your value as:

```
var_dump($o->getShowamounts());
```

Comment: As of `Symfony 2.6` you should/can use `dump()` instead of `var_dump()` which has a better handling of ORM objects and circular references.

Comment: And If you're using an older version you can use ```\Doctrine\Common\Util\Debug::dump($var);```